# Declaring a custom UIComponent in a taglib

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, custom-component

I'm creating a custom component class extending `HtmlSelectOneMenu` as follows:

```
@FacesComponent("pack.age.SelectOneInterval")
public class SelectOneInterval extends HtmlSelectOneMenu {

    @Override
    public void processValidators(FacesContext context){
        //Impl
    }

    @Override
    public void updateModel(FacesContext context) {
        //Impl
    }
}
```

The renderer for the compoenet will be the same as for `h:selectOneMenu` (i.e. `javax.faces.Menu` renderer type). The issue is I'd like to preserve all descriptions and all atttribute declarations as they are declared in JSF's `html_basic.taglib.xml`. I could just copy and paste them into `my_custom.taglib.xml` but it doesn't seem very good.

Comment: Unfortunately, taglibs doesn't support inheritance. Mojarra, PrimeFaces and MyFaces have homegrown taglib generators (XML resp annotation based). I'm also looking at it to reduce copypaste boilerplate in OmniFaces and I think a "standard" taglib generator which parses Java source code and javadocs would be very useful to JSF community.

Comment: @BalusC: Checked the 'RichFaces' solution? It did look useful to me 2 years ago.

Comment: @BalusC Don't quite understand.. I'm afraid that another developer which wil try to use the comoennt get confused by absence of all tags which are available as `h:selectOneMenu`...